# Dataset to excel

Tags: c#, excel, dataset

I'm developing an application that as to export a dataset to excel, this dataset have 3 tables and the relation between them, I would like to export this to a single excel sheet where for each parent table there is a '+' sign that when expanded shows the child values related to it. To export a single table to excel I know how to do it, but to create this type of relation I have no idea how to do it, do I have to create a macro on the excel file?

Answer (score 0):

I use a DevExpress Reports or a ActiveReports for this. I create a normal report and next i save it in xls, and Done. Its very complicated to this using us code. Its more easy to use a third-party components

Answer (score 0):

There's a free tool: https://closedxml.codeplex.com/ to create XLSX outputs from code.